# Coldfusion 2016 API Manager install problem - cannot view administrator

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am trying to install the 2016 API Manager Add-On Services but cannot access the administrator once the software has completed installing.

The Datastore and Analytics services install properly and are running (visible in Windows Services, and the install logs all look good).

But the next step in the install is to visit the administrator at port 9000 - and this page cannot be reached.

If I visit http://127.0.0.1:9200 I can see the 'Groot-elasticsearch' analytics server is available.

If I visit http://127.0.0.1:6379 I get a 'invalid http response' message but at least I can see that the datastore is running on that port.  I imagine that once I am able to get an API endpoint configured, I'll be able to access it here...

BUT, visiting http://127.0.0.1:9000/admin (or http://127.0.0.1:9000/portal.html) displays no sign that the API Manager is running on this port.  While the other two services' ports are configurable in the install, 9000 is the port Adobe uses for this administrator.  There is no separate service for the API Manager administrator.  I cannot find any help or on how to get started with the API Manager if you cannot first initially access the admin interface.

In [this troubleshooting document](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/unable-start-api-manager.html) they mention at the bottom that if there is a 'start-up issue' in case of 'In-VM installation', the the value of the parameter -Dapim.home can be changed within the CF server's jvm.config.  My install of Coldfusion *is* running on a VM, so this may be related... but this parameter was not set by the API manager installer in my jvm.config.

I've attempted to add it as a flag to java.args but no matter where I install the API Manager Add-on, and no matter what path I set with the format below, upon startup, I am given a warning message in CF's server log stating that 'The specified apim.home path does not exist'.

I'm adding this to the end of java.args:
 -Dapim.home={application.home}/APIManager/
(This example is when I installed the Manager Add-on in under the Coldfusion2016/cfusion/ directory, but I've tried countless other locations and path combinations. )

I'm at a loss as to why everything seems to be running except for the one required part to make any progress with the API Manager - the administrator interface.

Comment: Please note the API manager is now available for download via the Adobe Website. https://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/downloads.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have only installed the addon services. The CF2016 API manager installers are not available on Adobe website.
You can download the installer from below link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sDxjKt_OOz8P2tv4t1Aqbo7TT6flqv5U

If its installed "In-VM", The service startup is completely dependent on ColdFusion service. It starts along with CF servive.
I recommend you to re-install it from above mentioned link and have a seperate VM for API manager.

Comment: I'm sorry it's taken me so long to accept this answer.  You were absolutely correct.  It would be nice if Adobe provided the API manager download along with the API manager addon services...I don't know why they wouldn't!  Thank you for providing it!